# powershell image transformation

Tags: image, powershell, image-manipulation

I want to perform image transformation in powershell. Basically I want to insert a circle that contains different ratios of red/blue/green and yellow (this varies from picture to picture) onto another picture.

Right now I've stubmeld upon PSImageTools (http://psimagetools.start-automating.com/), but as far as I can tell, they only allow me to overlay one picture on to another, but since the ratios of the 4 colours vary, I have to dynamically create a circle that can be mapped onto the existing picture.

How can I perform the hardcore pixel that I require, not just pasting 2 images together, but defining the colour of the single pixel in powershell?

Comment: You should be able to use the [`System.Drawing.Graphics`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics(v=vs.110).aspx) class to do everything you need.

Comment: @Phylogenesis - I agree, currently my problem is getting the bitmap from the existing Image

Comment: But you are right - this solves my problem - thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following makes edits to an image:

```
$imageOld = "C:\My\File.jpg"
$imagenew = "C:\My\File2.jpg"

# Load the System.Windows.Forms library
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms");

$image    = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile($imageOld)
$graphics = [System.Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($image)

# 50% transparent white
$color    = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(128, 255, 255, 255)
$brush    = New-Object System.Drawing.SolidBrush($color)

# Draw a 500px circle located at (300, 300)
$graphics.FillEllipse($brush, 300, 300, 500, 500)

$image.Save($imageNew)
```